# Custom drawing on google maps using locations stored in Firebase database

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with drawing on maps. I need to draw something like these polygons (every group of locations as one polygon, at the same time all polygon are adjacent to each other and no intersection polygons occur) as in the bellow image ( something like grid ).
Locations stored in Firebase database.

[image]

Any Idea?, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Maps Polygon](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) to draw squares or simply use [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) to draw a circle over maps. Both accept LatLong.

Comment: Question updated for more clarification, thanks for helping

Comment: Read locations from Firebase and plot it on maps. I don't understand where are you facing the problem? are you not able to get locations from firebase or not able to plot it in maps?

Comment: the problem is to draw locations as polygons and not intersecting